# Get updated variable from within react hook before return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this custom fetch data hook

```
function fetchData(currentPage) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      axios.get(`https://${MY_API}${currentPage}`)
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }
    getData()
  }, [currentPage])

  return { data, error, loading }
}
```

Which is being used as such:

```
const { data, error, loading } = fetchData(currentPage)
```

So whenever the `currentPage` changes, the hook is called.

I'm having trouble getting the `loading` variable to change to true on changing page, it's always false which makes sense as that's what's being returned at the end of the hook.

How do I deal with resetting `loading` to false WITHIN the hook? Or is there another way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to simply fix your issue, the loading flag should be set by the effect itself:

```
function fetchData(currentPage) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    async function getData() {
      axios.get(`https://${MY_API}${currentPage}`)
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }
    getData()
  }, [currentPage])

  return { data, error, loading }
}
```

If you want to cancel pending requests and make sure they do not override the fetched data after page changes, you must cancel them out.
The easiest solution would be simply to ignore the response (`canceled` flag). However, [axios supports cancelation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) so the proper implementation is not that hard:

```
function fetchData(currentPage) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    let canceled = false;

    async function getData() {
      axios.get(
        `https://${MY_API}${currentPage}`,
        { cancelToken: source.token }
      )
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => {
          if (!axios.isCancel(err)) {
            setError(err);
          }
        }
        .finally(() => {
          if (!canceled) {
            setLoading(false)
          }
        )
    }

    setLoading(true);

    getData();

    return () => {
      canceled = true;
      source.cancel();
    }
  }, [currentPage])

  return { data, error, loading }
}
```

Comment: can you pass a hook state setter a second argument? I am not sure

Comment: You're right. I will redact my answer. However, the issue will be still present unless https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback or a similar workaround is used. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I think your solution to just add the `setLoading(true)` in `useEffect` is enough tbh

Answer (score 0):

### how about using await keyword?

```
function fetchData(currentPage) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(async () => {
    async function getData() {
      axios.get(`https://${MY_API}${currentPage}`)
       .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }
    await getData()
    getData()
  }, [currentPage])

  return { data, error, loading }
}
```